# Wrong number of arguments (Sinatra - rspec)

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I have a **Sinatra** application (trying to learn basic testing with rspec) and want to write a test for this method:

```
 # application_controller.rb
def active_page?(path)
  request.path_info == path
end
```

my test is

```
require File.expand_path '../../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__

describe "My Application Controller" do
  it "should validate the current page path" do
    get "/home"
    active_page?("/home").should eq true
  end
end
```

The error I get is

```
.F

Failures:

1) My Application Controller should validate the current page path
 Failure/Error: expect(active_page?("/home")).to be true

 ArgumentError:
   wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
 # /Users/deepthought/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rack-test-1.0.0/lib/rack/test.rb:116:in `request'
 # ./controllers/application_controller.rb:15:in `active_page?'
 # ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02004 seconds (files took 0.45736 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb:10 # My Application Controller should validate the current page path
```

The method itself seems to work fine in the application, but I wanted to write a test just for learning purposes.

At first I tried:

```
expect(active_page?("/home")).to eq true
```

but I still got the same error.

How do I make this test pass?

Comment: Try this : `expect(active_page?("/home")).to be true`

Comment: @AshikSalman unfortunately, I get the same error i.e. "wrong number of arguments..."

Comment: Can you update error stack trace in the question?

Comment: @AshikSalman I added the full error as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From spec, since get has been processed, you can't access request, but you can access last_request. I would change the code a bit like this

## application_controller.rb

```
def active_page?(requested, path)
  requested.path_info == path
end
```

## test

```
require File.expand_path '../../spec_helper.rb', __FILE__

describe "My Application Controller" do
  it "should validate the current page path" do
    get "/home"
    active_page?(last_request, "/home").should eq true
  end
end
```

Then, form your controller you would call the method like:
active_page?(request, "/home")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  it "should validate the current page path" do
    get "home"
    expect(controller.active_page?("/home")).to be true
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyApplicationController:0x00007f857ba19458> is the error I get now. The method comes from a file called application_controller.rb

Comment: Is it a private method ?

Comment: nope! no private/protected or anything like that. It is not even a class. it just a ruby file with that method in my OP.

Comment: I was thinking that method reside inside application controller. Thats why I mentioned `ApplicationController ` in describe block so that we get `controller` instance in rspec test. How can you access `request` from just a ruby file ?

Comment: This is a lightweight Sinatra application. Files are required in my main app.rb file. I made some other tests with the same file and they all work. I thought this was more of an rspec syntax sort of deal. Also, request does work. The functionality works great. I just wanted to write a test for it since it looked simple enough